# How to dismiss error message when exec reg query command

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm trying to delete some HKEY if exists using a batch script and I wonder to dismiss this error message when the key doesn't exist:

[image]

```
echo ====================================================================
echo %date% - %time% : Remove Some HKEY
echo ====================================================================

reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Settings" /v "AB12" >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  echo deleting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Settings\AB12
  REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Settings" /v "AB12" /f
)
```

Comment: Redirect the error message to the `NUL` device. All you need therefore is `REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Settings" /V "AB12" /F 2>NUL`, or two lines, `ECHO Deleting any AB12 value under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Settings`, followed by `REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Settings" /V "AB12" /F 2>NUL`.

Comment: It doesn't work because the error message comes from the reg query command and not the reg delete.

Comment: You do not need the reg query command! Did you not read my comment above, _"All you need"_. Also, even with the 'reg query' command, you could still redirect the error message to the same `NUL` device.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine :)